# How to show first post content and links for older post only in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create news paper web site and need help to show the content of recent post and title of old posts only... here is my code

```
<?php
   $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'id',
                'hide_empty' => 1,
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
    $categories = get_categories($args);
    foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <div class="newsdiv">
            <?php
                echo '<center><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a></center> <br/> ';
                $post_args = array(
                         'numberposts' => 3,
                         'category' => $category->term_id 
                        );

                $posts = get_posts($post_args);

                foreach($posts as $post) {?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo"*";the_title(); ?></a>
                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                } 
                echo '<dd class="view-all"> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>Read more </a></dd>';
                echo '</dl>';
            ?>
        </div>
<?php   
    } 
?>
```

Comment: and the problem is ... ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the codex previous post

```
<?php previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_cat = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ); ?>
```

you can use it in simpler and/or complex way something like this.

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
```

for more info you can go through with codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link